# Trouble running forever on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

I am trying to install forever to run my nodeJS app. I used npm to install forever

```
npm install forever -g
```

now when I try to run my app using the following command, nothing happens (no error message)

```
forever server.js
```

when I check pidof forever, I get nothing. What could I be doing wring? The instructions seem fairly straight forward

Comment: `nothing happens` in this case meaning that your app simply exits and does not start the server?

Comment: no my server does not start. When I check the process id of forever, nothing gets returned so nothing is running.

Comment: Just to be safe, run `which forever` and make sure it's the node module you're expecting.

Comment: Yes its the correct file. Although I just realized that I cannot run anything installed using npm. I get the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to this problem. If you used apt-get to install node, it is mapped to nodejs, not node.

head to /usr/local/bin/ and edit forever

```
vim /usr/local/bin/forever
```

change this line

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
```